# Error callback always fired, even when it is successful

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

There should be a glitch in my syntax, or something I haven't understood, but when I am doing a save method on my model. The error callback is called whatever the outcome of the method.

```
    @new_activity = new Activity()

    @new_activity.save
        know: $('input#know').val()
        learn: $('input#learn').val()

        success: -> console.log 'success'
        error: -> console.log 'error'
```

In my case, since I do not really know whether the new_activity has effectively passed the validation, I have to do an ugly trick to add the activity to the collection. (By the way, I do not use the create method since I do want to have the different errors, and not a simple "false".

```
    if @new_activity.has('know') and @new_activity.has('learn')
        app.collections.activities.add @new_activity
```

When it is successful though; there is an alert of the created model.

**Edit:** Further details.
Here is my model:
    initialize: ->
        _.bindAll @, 'validate', 'errorHandler'
        @.bind 'error', @errorHandler

```
validate: (attrs) ->
    errors = []
    # We only support a certain number of languages, we enforce that the user does not select a wrong set.
    if _.isEmpty(_.intersection([attrs.know], ['en', 'fr'])) is true
        errors.push 'This language is not currently supported.'

    if _.isEmpty(_.intersection([attrs.learn], ['en', 'fr', 'de', 'es', 'zh', 'pt', 'ar', 'ja', 'ru'])) is true
        errors.push 'You cannot learn this language yet.'

    if _.isEmpty(errors) is false
        errors

errorHandler: (model, error) ->
    console.log error
```

When the validation occurs, and if the validate method returns nothing, it still triggers the error event, and the error variable contains the model (but no error message).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check whether the new_activity is saved properly, please verify that the server returns success response to the PUT request.

Furthermore, I have had issues with using Rails 3.1 standard `format.json { head :ok }` because it returns a single space as a reponse and application/json as content type. Backbone then tries to parse JSON and dies with an error.

Comment: So what should we send on a json success?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the single space that Rails sends back with `head :ok`. If you send back an empty string, Backbone handles it fine.

The proper way to do that is to send back a `204 No Content`. You can do that by replacing `head :ok` with `head :no_content` in the `format.json` block. Rails will not send back anything in the HTTP body.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the cause of your error is, but I think I can help you pin it down:

Looking at the [annotated source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html) for Backbone.js, you can see that `save()` defers to `sync()`, which in turn defers to jQuery's [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). So ultimately, your `error` function (wrapped by Backbone's `wrapError`) is called from that.

Unfortunately, the wrapper discards all but the `jqXHR` argument, making debugging a bit tricky. So you might want to try hacking your local Backbone.js source file to replace the existing `wrapError`function with something like this:

```
var wrapError = function(onError, model, options) {
    return function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(jqXHR);
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(errorThrown);
      if (onError) {
        onError(model, jqXHR, options);
      } else {
        model.trigger('error', model, jqXHR, options);
      }
    };
  };
```

Then, at least, you'll see all of the debugging data provided by jQuery on your console.