# Backbone.js save behaving weird

Tags: ajax, backbone.js, express

I create a new model (msg) and save it like below:

```
msg.save({}, {success: this.createSuccess, error: function(model, response){
  console.log('nay', response);
}});
```

Now the server returns **status: 200** and **statusText: "OK"** but still the error callback is called.

The model has no validation nor does the server (Express.js).

What could I've overlooked?

I'm using the latest version of Backbone and Express…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you returning anything in your body?  If all you are returning is 200 OK in the head, then you will get an error.  You should return the JSON representation of the saved item (including the id, which is really important for updates/deletes later) from your server.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return an empty response, the response code should be `204 No Content`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9104241/157943.